# Set gift message to existing order programmatically

Tags: php, magento

I'm looking for a bit of code to add a gift message to existing order programmatically in Magento.

====================

An update

I like that moderators (@Charles, etc etc) flagged this question as not real even though it had 228 views - obviously no one really having same issue... lol Would be great to see up-vote from everyone who reads it. How much more specific can you be? lol

Comment: Checkout -> http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-displaying-adding-gift-message-in-order/

Comment: Yer, I was after adding it programmatically :-/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$giftMessage = Mage::getModel('giftmessage/message'); 
$giftMessage->setCustomerId($customer->getId()); 
$giftMessage->setSender('sender']); 
$giftMessage->setRecipient('recepient'); 
$giftMessage->setMessage('message'); 
$giftObj = $giftMessage->save(); 
$order->setGiftMessageId($giftObj->getId()); 
$order->save();
```

Comment: Thanks very much for answering this dude! was very helpful.

Comment: @Miroslav hey what if I want to add gift message on product basis for an order? Like for each product in cart different message should be saved.