# magento : How to add custom form in cart page?

Tags: magento

I want to add gift message option at cart page. and I want to pass on filled text.

want this detail in control panel.

Comment: magento already have a gift options in manage products

Comment: But I want it on cart page and not on other.

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12009330/725306 hope this might help you a bit